# Using Compress and Scan in SAS to create new variable

Tags: sas, compression

I am new to SAS and would like to keep only what's in between the parentheses of another column in my new column using compress and SCAN:

```
 x 
abc(animal)
efg(food)
hij(plant)
```

I tried:

```
DATA NEW 
    set OLD;
    y = (compress(scan([x], 2, '('), ')');
RUN;
PROC PRINT NEW; 
RUN;
```

but I can't seem to get it to work. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Does the value always have something before the open paren? Does it always have one and only one set of parentheses?

Answer (score 3):

@tom answer is perfect and another way to do this is using prxsubstr.

```
 data have;
 input x $20.;
 datalines;
abc(animal)
efg(food)
hij(plant)
;

 prxparse \(.+?\) is to find anything between parenthesis
 \( -- starting of parenthesis
 .+?\( ---  anything till closing parenthesis
```

call prxsubstr captures where it finds pattern and length of it.
then doing substr to get the values inside the parenthesis

```
data want;
set have;
if _n_= 1 then do;
retain re;
re = prxparse('/\(.+?\)/');
end;
call prxsubstr(re, trim(x), position, length);

if position gt 0 then 
 new=substr(trim(x),position+1, length-2);
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

There should be no need for `compress()`, unless you want to remove some other characters from the value extracted.  You might want to use `left()` to remove leading spaces from values like `xxx(  yyy )`.

```
y=scan(x,2,'()');
```

If you have some values like `(no first word)` then you might need to use index of 1 instead of two.  If so you could use `=:` to test if X starts with an open paren.

```
y=scan(x,1+(x^=:'('),'()');
```

If you know the () are always at the end you could use index of -1.  But again if some strings had characters after the close paren then you would need to use -2 instead.